# How to use the vehicle inState command in AB model

Tags: anylogic

In a supply chain with GIS model, I am trying to calculate travel distance using the event on main between a factory and retailers using the following event. And I get this error message:

`The method Instate( Vehicles. statechart_state) is undefined by the state T`.

What does this mean?

Is there another way to calculate total distance between facilities?

I have tried `DistanceByRoute(agent)` but could not get any output.

```
Vehicles vehicles = getRandom(filter(vehicles, v -> v.inState(Vehicles.AtRetailers) ) );if (vehicles != null) {send("go", vehicles);}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is hinting at your code checking the agent state. Try this instead:

```
Vehicles vehicles = getRandom(filter(vehicles, v -> v.mySDtatechart.isStateActive(Vehicles.AtRetailers) ) );
```

Where "myStateChart" is the state chart in your Vehicle agent class and "AtRetailers" is the state you are checking in myStateChart.

Comment: Thank you Benjamin, it worked. I am actually looking for a way to calculate travel distance which will eventually help in calculating the transportation costs in Supply chain GIS model. Have tried distanceByRoute ( doesn't work), figured out that I could use the log file for distances. Is there a better way to calculate travel distance in AB Anylogic model with GIS?

Comment: Glad it worked, please mark this question as answered, then. And ideally post your new questions separately so other people can benefit from it as well in the future 